# How to adjust block heights regardless of the height of another block in the grid?

Tags: html, css

I want to make some blocks independent of the height of others, is it possible to do this?
How can I make my second box's height not depend on the height of the first one. Accordingly, box 4 should be pressed at the bottom of box 2?

```css
.wrapper {
  max-width: 1200px;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 0 0px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(10, 1fr);
  grid-auto-rows: minmax(10px, auto);
  grid-gap: 1em;
  justify-items: stretch;
  align-items: stretch;
}

.wrapper>div {
  padding: 1em;
  background-color: #d7cfe79f;
}

.box-1 {
  grid-column: 1/7;
}

.box-2 {
  grid-column: 7/11;
}

.box-3 {
  grid-column: 1/7;
}

.box-4 {
  grid-column: 7/11;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="box box-1">Box 1<br/><br/><br/></div>
  <div class="box box-2">Box 2</div>
  <div class="box box-3">Box 3</div>
  <div class="box box-4">Box 4</div>
</div>
```

Expected Result:
[image]

Comment: @connexo I added expected result

Comment: Can you suggest an alternative in your answer?

Comment: You will have to create two additional column wrapper elements (which then become your grid cells), then use `display: flex` inside those to arrange the actual boxes.

Comment: @np. you have to use grid model?

Comment: I have suggested two alternatives in my answer.

Answer (score -1):

You are looking for a [**masonry**](https://www.smashingmagazine.com/native-css-masonry-layout-css-grid/) type of layout, which can be achieved using [the new `masonry` keyworded value for `grid-template-rows`](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-grid-3/#background):

```
grid-template-rows: masonry;
```

**Please note that [this feature hasn't officially landed in any browser yet](https://caniuse.com/mdn-css_properties_grid-template-rows_masonry), so it's nothing you can apply for production use.**

If you want to see it in action, use Firefox, open a new tab and enter `about:config` there. Confirm the security question, then type *masonry* in the searchbar.

This will show the experimental feature and allow you to enable it (set it to `true`). It's under

```
layout.css.grid-template-masonry-value.enabled
```

Until then, you will need workarounds like manually creating column wrappers, or use something like [masonry.js](https://masonry.desandro.com/).

Here's how Firefox renders it with the experimental masonry feature enabled:

[image]

```css
.wrapper {
  max-width: 1200px;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 0 0px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(10, 1fr);
  grid-template-rows: masonry;
  grid-gap: 1em;
  justify-items: stretch;
  align-items: stretch;
}

.wrapper>div {
  padding: 1em;
  background-color: #d7cfe79f;
}

.box-1 {
  grid-column: 1/7;
}

.box-2 {
  grid-column: 7/11;
}

.box-3 {
  grid-column: 1/7;
}

.box-4 {
  grid-column: 7/11;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="box box-1">Box 1<br/><br/><br/></div>
  <div class="box box-2">Box 2</div>
  <div class="box box-3">Box 3</div>
  <div class="box box-4">Box 4</div>
</div>
```